# Output of this simple C program

Tags: c, recursion

I'm an intermediate programmer of C++. I came across this code which prints number from 1-1000 without loop, not even recursion. And I've literally no idea how is this working. Can any please explain this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function(int j)
{
    static void (*const ft[2])(int) = { function, exit };

    printf("%d\n", j);
    ft[j/1000](j + 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 function(1);
}
```

Comment: This is recursion, sort of.

Comment: That's `c`, not `c++`.

Comment: @NATS  At last I have known what  the term "intermediate programmer of C++"' means. Thanks.

Comment: hahahah.. :D
#SorryForInconvience

Comment: Please note that this is just a nonsense program written to be intentionally silly. Nobody professional would write code like this in real life.

Comment: `function(2000); // millenium bug?`

Comment: yes, this was a sort of challenge to print number 1-1000 without using a loop

Comment: actually, the code does not cleanly compile.  the parameters: `argc` and `argv[]` are not used and will cause the compiler to output two warnings messages.   Since the parameters are not used, suggest using the signature: `int main( void )` for the `main()` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just simple recursion:

```
static void (*const ft[2])(int) = { function, exit };
```

First a function pointer array is created with fpointers to `function` and `exit`, both taking an `int`.

Then `ft[j/1000](j + 1);` calls the function at element `[j/1000]` which is `0` as long as `j` is less than 1000, so `function` is called, otherwise `exit` is called.

Comment: where does ft came from. it's never defined anywhere

Comment: @NATS Yes it is, the array that contains the function pointers is called `ft`, the function pointer declaration syntax is just a bit hard to read. P.S use backticks to have code in comments `.

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously recursive, it contains a 2-element array of function pointers and calls either itself (`ft[0]` is  `function`) or `exit()` to exit the program.

This line:

```
ft[j/1000](j + 1);
```

is a recursive call for as long as `j/1000` evaluates to `0`. It can be rewritten as:

```
if(j < 1000)
  function(j + 1);
else
  exit(j + 1);
```

Comment: can you please tell my why my question got "-1" ?

Comment: @NATS No, I don't know. I didn't down-vote. It could be because of the C vs C++ confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function `function` there is declared a pointer to the function itself as an element of an array

```
static void (*const ft[2])(int) = { function, exit };
                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

So inside the function these calls

```
f( j + 1 );
```

and

```
ft[0]( j + 1 );
```

are equivalent.

The expression

```
j / 1000
```

is always equal to 0 due to the integer arithmetic until `j` is equal to `1000`.

Thus the function recursively calls itself 1000 times. When `j` is equal to `1000` then the function exit is called because `ft[1]` is pointer to `exit`.

The program can be written much simpler and clear. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function(int j)
{
    printf("%d\n", j);
    if ( j / 1000 == 0 ) f( j + 1 );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    function( 1 );
}
```

The only difference is that in the original program there is called exit with argument `1001` while this program successfully exits with argument 0.